# arctan and arcsin equation

Tags: trigonometry, angle

How can I prove that :

> $2 \arctan(x) + \arcsin \Big( \frac{ 2x }{  1 + x^2 }\Big) = \pi$ , $x > 1$

What is the best way  to do this ?

Comment: I gave correct answer but still no point.

Comment: Assume $x=\tan\theta$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can prove it without differentiating:  set $t=2\arctan x$. This means 
$$\tan\frac t2=x\quad\text{and}\quad -\pi <t<\pi.$$
Furthermore, as $x>1$, we have $\;\dfrac\pi2<t<\pi$.

Now, by the half-angle formulae (actually this is where the formula we seek to prove comes from),
$$\sin t=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}, \quad\text{whence}\quad t\equiv \begin{cases}\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\quad\text{or}
\\ \pi -\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\end{cases}\mod2\pi.$$
Knowing $\;\dfrac\pi2<t<\pi$, we necessarily have
$$t=2\arctan x= \pi -\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Yes, I like this approach best.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to differentiate the function
$$f(x)=2\arctan(x)+\arcsin\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$
and show that $f'(x)=0$ so that $f$ is a constant. Then calculate the constant by letting $x$ be a well-chosen number.

Answer (score 2):

Let put  $x=tan(\frac{t}{2})$ with

$t\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$ cause $x>1$

then

$1+x^2=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\frac{t}{2})}$

and

$f(x)=t+arcsin(\sin(t))$

$=t-arcsin(\sin(t-\pi))$.

but $-\frac{\pi}{2}<t-\pi<0$, thus

$f(x)=t-t+\pi=\pi$.

Comment: You should explain why $\arcsin(\sin t)$.